# Apache POI Line chart points

Tags: java, apache-poi, linechart

I am creating an Excel file with line chart. I've created chart and filled it with data but I need values to be shown on each of the points. Is there a way I could show  these values on points in a chart using apache poi 4.1.1 version?

Layout of the chart,Currently coming as output

[image]

Layout of the chart which i want

[image]

Sample Code:

```
createChartFromPivotTable( xssfSheet, "Generated", 6, 6 + NO_OF_DAYS - 1, 5, 13, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 );


private void createChartFromPivotTable( XSSFSheet sheet, String title, int valueFirstRow, int valueLastRow, int startRow, int endRow, int xCol1, int xCol2, int ycol1, int ycol2, int addNum ) {
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor( 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, startRow, 14, endRow );

    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart( anchor );
    chart.setTitleText( "LineChart" );
    chart.setTitleOverlay( false );

    XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
    legend.setPosition( LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT );

    XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis( AxisPosition.BOTTOM );
    bottomAxis.setTitle( "Offer Date" );
    XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis( AxisPosition.LEFT );
    leftAxis.setTitle( "Count" );
    XDDFDataSource<String> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange( sheet, new CellRangeAddress( valueFirstRow, valueLastRow, xCol1, xCol2 ) );
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange( sheet, new CellRangeAddress( valueFirstRow, valueLastRow, ycol1, ycol2 ) );
    XDDFLineChartData data = ( XDDFLineChartData ) chart.createData( ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis );
    data.setVaryColors( false );
    XDDFLineChartData.Series series = ( XDDFLineChartData.Series ) data.addSeries( xs, ys1 );
    series.setTitle( title, null );
    series.setSmooth( false );
    series.setMarkerStyle( MarkerStyle.STAR );
    chart.plot( data );

    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray( 0 ).addNewAxId().setVal( bottomAxis.getId() );
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray( 0 ).addNewAxId().setVal( leftAxis.getId() );

    // plot area background and border line
    if ( chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr() == null )
        chart.getCTChartSpace().addNewSpPr();
    if ( chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getSolidFill() == null )
        chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().addNewSolidFill();
    if ( chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getSolidFill().getSrgbClr() == null )
        chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr();
    chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getSolidFill().getSrgbClr().setVal( new byte[] { ( byte ) 255, ( byte ) 255, ( byte ) 255 } );
    if ( chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getLn() == null )
        chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().addNewLn();
    chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getLn().setW( Units.pixelToEMU( 1 ) );
    if ( chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill() == null )
        chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getLn().addNewSolidFill();
    if ( chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill().getSrgbClr() == null )
        chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr();
    chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill().getSrgbClr().setVal( new byte[] { ( byte ) 0, ( byte ) 0, ( byte ) 0 } );

    // line style of cat axis
    if ( chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr() == null )
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray( 0 ).addNewSpPr();
    if ( chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn() == null )
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().addNewLn();
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().setW( Units.pixelToEMU( 1 ) );
    if ( chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill() == null )
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().addNewSolidFill();
    if ( chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill().getSrgbClr() == null )
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr();
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getCatAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill().getSrgbClr().setVal( new byte[] { ( byte ) 0, ( byte ) 0, ( byte ) 0 } );

    //line style of val axis
    if ( chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr() == null )
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray( 0 ).addNewSpPr();
    if ( chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn() == null )
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().addNewLn();
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().setW( Units.pixelToEMU( 1 ) );
    if ( chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill() == null )
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().addNewSolidFill();
    if ( chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill().getSrgbClr() == null )
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr();
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getValAxArray( 0 ).getSpPr().getLn().getSolidFill().getSrgbClr().setVal( new byte[] { ( byte ) 0, ( byte ) 0, ( byte ) 0 } );

    XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties( XDDFColor.from( PresetColor.BLUE ) );
    XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
    line.setFillProperties( fill );
    for ( XDDFChartData.Series series1 : data.getSeries() ) {
        XDDFShapeProperties properties = series1.getShapeProperties();
        if ( properties == null ) {
            properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
        }
        properties.setLineProperties( line );
        series1.setShapeProperties( properties );
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide a sample code to generate your current chart?

Comment: @OnurBaştürk Please find the sample code above.

Answer (score 0):

yes

```
 series.setTitle(" ", chart.setSheetTitle(" ", 0))
 series.setShowLeaderLines(true)
```